# C# iText crear PDF similar a una impresora de ticket

Tags: c#, itext

Alguien me puede ayudar, estoy tratando de generar un PDF, para guardar el PDF de las facturas impresas una impresora de EPSON T88IV, por lo tanto el documento no es hoja OFICIO o carta sino que mi hoja es de 8cm por un largo de n.

Alguien sabe como trabajar esto en iText7??

Gracias!!

Les dejo mi código, espero no me traten de tonto uso iText, pero este tiene un monton de formatos de hoja, la que necesito es una de 8cm x Ncm.

iText esta enbebida en esta clase:

```
namespace PrinterPDF
{
    public class TicketPDF
    {
        public TicketPDF()
        {

            myDocument.AddAuthor("Xauro sistemas");
            myDocument.AddCreator("José Donoso Moscoso");
            myDocument.AddTitle("Venta");
           
        }

        PdfWriter writer = null;
        PdfContentByte cb = null;
        ArrayList headerLines = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList subHeaderLines = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList totales = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList footerLines = new ArrayList();
        private string headerImage = "";
        bool _DrawItemHeaders = true;
        int count = 0;
        string path = "";
        string file_name = "";
        int maxChar = 40;
        int maxCharDescription = 20;
        int imageHeight = 0;
        float leftMargin = 0;
        float topMargin = 5;
        static int fontSize = 7;

        static BaseFont bfCourier = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.COURIER, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
        static Font font = new Font(bfCourier, fontSize, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

        Document myDocument = new Document(PageSize.LETTER); //Aqui se ponen todos los objetos

        

        string line = "";

        #region Properties

        public String Path
        {
            get { return path; }
            set { path = value; }
        }

        public String FileName
        {
            get { return file_name; }
            set { file_name = value; }
        }

        public String FullFileName
        {
            get { return (String.Format("{0}{1}", path, file_name)); }
        }
        public String HeaderImage
        {
            get { return headerImage; }
            set { if (headerImage != value) headerImage = value; }
        }

        public int MaxChar
        {
            get { return maxChar; }
            set { if (value != maxChar) maxChar = value; }
        }

        public bool DrawItemHeaders
        {
            set { _DrawItemHeaders = value; }
        }

        public int MaxCharDescription
        {
            get { return maxCharDescription; }
            set { if (value != maxCharDescription) maxCharDescription = value; }
        }

        public int FontSize
        {
            get { return fontSize; }
            set { if (value != fontSize) fontSize = value; }
        }

        public Font FontName
        {
            get { return font; }
            set { if (value != font) font = value; }
        }

        #endregion

        public void AddHeaderLine(string line)
        {
            headerLines.Add(line);
        }

        public void AddSubHeaderLine(string line)
        {
            subHeaderLines.Add(line);
        }

        public void AddItem(string cantidad, string item, string price)
        {
            TicketOrderItem newItem = new TicketOrderItem('?');
            items.Add(newItem.GenerateItem(cantidad, item, price));
        }

        public void AddTotal(string name, string price)
        {
            TicketOrderTotal newTotal = new TicketOrderTotal('?');
            totales.Add(newTotal.GenerateTotal(name, price));
        }

        public void AddFooterLine(string line)
        {
            footerLines.Add(line);
        }

        private string AlignRightText(int lenght)
        {
            string espacios = "";
            int spaces = maxChar - lenght;
            for (int x = 0; x < spaces; x++)
                espacios += " ";
            return espacios;
        }

        private string DottedLine()
        {
            string dotted = "";
            for (int x = 0; x < maxChar; x++)
                dotted += "=";
            return dotted;
        }

        public bool Print()
        {
            try
            {
                //aqui para generar el PDF
                writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(myDocument, new FileStream(path + file_name, FileMode.Create));
                myDocument.Open();
                cb = writer.DirectContent;
                cb.SetFontAndSize(font.BaseFont, fontSize);
                cb.BeginText();
                DrawImage();
                DrawHeader();
                DrawSubHeader();
                DrawItems();
                DrawTotales();
                DrawFooter();
                cb.EndText();
                myDocument.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw (ex);
            }
        }

        private float YPosition()
        {
            return (myDocument.PageSize.Height -
                (topMargin + (count * font.CalculatedSize + imageHeight)));
        }

        private void DrawImage()
        {
            try
            {
                if ((headerImage != null) && (headerImage != ""))
                {
                    if (File.Exists(headerImage))
                    {
                        Image logo = Image.GetInstance(headerImage);
                        double height = ((double)logo.Height / 58) * 15;
                        imageHeight = (int)Math.Round(height) + 3;
                        logo.SetAbsolutePosition(0,
                            myDocument.PageSize.Height - imageHeight);
                        logo.ScaleToFit(logo.Width, imageHeight);
                        myDocument.Add(logo);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { throw (ex); }
        }

        private void DrawHeader()
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (string header in headerLines)
                {
                    if (header.Length > maxChar)
                    {
                        int currentChar = 0;
                        int headerLenght = header.Length;
                        while (headerLenght > maxChar)
                        {
                            line = header.Substring(currentChar, maxChar);
                            cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                            cb.ShowText(line);
                            count++;
                            currentChar += maxChar;
                            headerLenght -= maxChar;
                        }
                        line = header;
                        cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                        cb.ShowText(line.Substring(currentChar,
                            line.Length - currentChar));
                        count++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        line = header;
                        cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                        cb.ShowText(line);
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                DrawEspacio();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { throw (ex); }
        }

        private void DrawSubHeader()
        {
            try
            {
                line = DottedLine();
                cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                cb.ShowText(line);
                DrawEspacio();
                foreach (string subHeader in subHeaderLines)
                {
                    if (subHeader.Length > maxChar)
                    {
                        int currentChar = 0;
                        int subHeaderLenght = subHeader.Length;
                        while (subHeaderLenght > maxChar)
                        {
                            line = subHeader;
                            cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                            cb.ShowText(line.Substring(currentChar, maxChar));
                            count++;
                            currentChar += maxChar;
                            subHeaderLenght -= maxChar;
                        }
                        line = subHeader;
                        cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                        cb.ShowText(line.Substring(currentChar,
                            line.Length - currentChar));
                        count++;
                        line = DottedLine();
                        cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                        cb.ShowText(line);
                        DrawEspacio();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        line = subHeader;
                        cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                        cb.ShowText(line);
                        count++;
                        line = DottedLine();
                        cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                        cb.ShowText(line);
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                DrawEspacio();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { throw (ex); }
        }

        private void DrawItems()
        {
            TicketOrderItem ordIt = new TicketOrderItem('?');
            if (_DrawItemHeaders)
            {
                cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                cb.ShowText("CANT  DESCRIPCION                IMPORTE");
            }
            count++;
            DrawEspacio();
            foreach (string item in items)
            {
                line = ordIt.GetItemCantidad(item);
                cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                cb.ShowText(line);
                line = ordIt.GetItemPrice(item);
                line = AlignRightText(line.Length) + line;
                cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                cb.ShowText(line);
                string name = ordIt.GetItemName(item);
                leftMargin = 0;
                if (name.Length > maxCharDescription)
                {
                    int currentChar = 0;
                    int itemLenght = name.Length;
                    while (itemLenght > maxCharDescription)
                    {
                        line = ordIt.GetItemName(item);
                        cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                        cb.ShowText("      " + line.Substring(currentChar,
                            maxCharDescription));
                        count++;
                        currentChar += maxCharDescription;
                        itemLenght -= maxCharDescription;
                    }
                    line = ordIt.GetItemName(item);
                    cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                    cb.ShowText("      " + line.Substring(currentChar,
                        maxCharDescription));
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                    cb.ShowText("      " + ordIt.GetItemName(item));
                    count++;
                }
            }

            leftMargin = 0;
            DrawEspacio();
            line = DottedLine();
            cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
            cb.ShowText(line);
            count++;
            DrawEspacio();
        }

        private void DrawTotales()
        {
            TicketOrderTotal ordTot = new TicketOrderTotal('?');
            foreach (string total in totales)
            {
                line = ordTot.GetTotalCantidad(total);
                line = AlignRightText(line.Length) + line;
                cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                cb.ShowText(line);
                leftMargin = 0;
                line = "" + ordTot.GetTotalName(total);
                cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                cb.ShowText(line);
                count++;
            }
            leftMargin = 0;
            DrawEspacio();
            DrawEspacio();
        }

        private void DrawFooter()
        {
            foreach (string footer in footerLines)
            {
                if (footer.Length > maxChar)
                {
                    int currentChar = 0;
                    int footerLenght = footer.Length;
                    while (footerLenght > maxChar)
                    {
                        line = footer;
                        cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                        cb.ShowText(line.Substring(currentChar, maxChar));
                        count++;
                        currentChar += maxChar;
                        footerLenght -= maxChar;
                    }
                    line = footer;
                    cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                    cb.ShowText(line.Substring(currentChar, maxChar));
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    line = footer;
                    cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
                    cb.ShowText(line);
                    count++;
                }
            }
            leftMargin = 0;
            DrawEspacio();
        }

        private void DrawEspacio()
        {
            line = "";
            cb.SetTextMatrix(leftMargin, YPosition());
            cb.SetFontAndSize(font.BaseFont, fontSize);
            cb.ShowText(line);
            count++;
        }
    }

    public class TicketOrderItem
    {
        char[] delimitador = new char[] { '?' };
        public TicketOrderItem(char delimit)
        {
            delimitador = new char[] { delimit };
        }

        public string GetItemCantidad(string TicketOrderItem)
        {
            string[] delimitado = TicketOrderItem.Split(delimitador);
            return delimitado[0];
        }

        public string GetItemName(string TicketOrderItem)
        {
            string[] delimitado = TicketOrderItem.Split(delimitador);
            return delimitado[1];
        }

        public string GetItemPrice(string TicketOrderItem)
        {
            string[] delimitado = TicketOrderItem.Split(delimitador);
            return delimitado[2];
        }

        public string GenerateItem(string cantidad,
            string itemName, string price)
        {
            return cantidad + delimitador[0] +
                itemName + delimitador[0] + price;
        }
    }

    public class TicketOrderTotal
    {
        char[] delimitador = new char[] { '?' };
        public TicketOrderTotal(char delimit)
        {
            delimitador = new char[] { delimit };
        }

        public string GetTotalName(string totalItem)
        {
            string[] delimitado = totalItem.Split(delimitador);
            return delimitado[0];
        }

        public string GetTotalCantidad(string totalItem)
        {
            string[] delimitado = totalItem.Split(delimitador);
            return delimitado[1];
        }

        public string GenerateTotal(string totalName,
            string price)
        {
            return totalName + delimitador[0] + price;
        }
    }
}
```

Se usa de la siguiente manera:

```
public static void CrearBoleta(DTE dte, string pathOut = null)
{
    TicketPDF boleta = new TicketPDF();
    boleta.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathOut)+"\\";
    boleta.FileName =  $"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pathOut)}.PDF";
    boleta.HeaderImage = null;

    boleta.AddHeaderLine("TICKET_HEADER_01");
    boleta.AddHeaderLine("TICKET_HEADER_02");
    boleta.AddHeaderLine("TICKET_HEADER_03");
    boleta.AddHeaderLine("TICKET_HEADER_04");
    boleta.AddHeaderLine("TICKET_HEADER_05");

    boleta.AddSubHeaderLine("Dato 1");
    boleta.AddSubHeaderLine("Dato 2");
    boleta.AddSubHeaderLine("Dato 3");
    boleta.AddSubHeaderLine("Dato 4");
    boleta.AddSubHeaderLine("Dato 5");

    int Cantidad = 1;
    string Producto = "Stacarbone 100";
    int Total = 1500;
    // Detalles
    boleta.AddItem( Cantidad.ToString(), Producto.Substring(0, 11), Total.ToString() );

    boleta.Print();

}
```

Genera esta salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero yo necesito algo similar al ticket que emito por la impresora:
Ejemplo de una boleta de otro sistema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Itext permite varios formatos de hoja, pero no veo alguno similar a 8cm x Ncm.

```
 Document myDocument = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
```

Creo que en iText7 se puede.

fredyfx
ahora con mas antecedentes espero puedas ver que si algo se de codificación y tan tonto no soy.

Ayudame a resolver mi tema desde los cielos!

Saludos a todos!!!

Comment: No son moderadores endiosados, tu pregunta anterior no cumple con las normas del sitio. De hecho esta tampoco, porque debiste editar la pregunta original siguiendo las sugerencias. Todos somos moderadores del sitio y debemos velar por la buena calidad tanto de preguntas como de respuestas. Tu actitud al exponer y resaltar públicamente un comentario correcto no es lo que se espera de los miembros de la comunidad. Existe un [código de conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct), trata de apegarte al mismo.

Comment: 1. Nadie te ha tratado de tonto. 2. En lugar de tomar a pecho un comentario _en donde se te dio una sugerencia, sin que se te haya faltado al respeto_, y tal como te han indicado, debiste editar la pregunta anterior. Ahora tenés preguntas duplicadas: elegí cuál de ellas vas a mantener, y mejorá la que elijas, _evitando por sobre todo el ruido_. Leé [ask], y no olvides al [código de conducta](/conduct).

Comment: La pregunta anterior esta bloqueada despues de editarla no pude actualizarla, no nos enfrasquemos en dichos y diretes. Si sabes del tema esperaría colaboración, las cartas estan hechadas y el que lea puede juzgar.

Comment: Esto no es un juzgado, aquí no se viene a juzgar a nadie, tu pregunta anterior no parece cerrada ni bloqueada. No se trata de dichos y diretes, esto no es una red antisocial como Twitter, aquí queremos ayudarte, no nos pagan por ello y no es una obligación. Lo único que se te pide es que seas respetuoso de las normas del sitio. Al final, el único perjudicado eres tú. Es probable que tu capacidad para realizar preguntas en el sitio se vea limitada por tener publicaciones de mala calidad. Mi sugerencia, si la quieres tomar: elimina una de las 2 publicaciones y apégate al formato de [es.so].

Comment: La verdad, pocas ganas se le quedan a uno de ayudar con semejante publicación. Cuando entras a una comunidad debes atenerte a sus reglas y lo que acabas de hacer es una total falta de respeto. Nadie acá es envidioso de nadie, hay unas normas que cumplir. Si no hubiera sido @fredyfx, hubiera sido cualquiera.

Comment: entonces no ayude, siempre habra quien en vez de centrarse en el como, mirará el fondo y simplemente ayudara, SIEMPRE QUE SEPA, lo otro es hablar de lo que  pueda!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lamentablemente ya he leído en otras ocasiones a usuarios más preocupados sobre como se describen los problemas mas que ayudar.

Amigo no te preocupes, como dices tu siempre hay gente que quiera ayudar y
Entendí perfectamente lo que indicas.

**Lo que debes hacer es reemplazar:**

```
Document myDocument = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
```

**por**

```
Document myDocument = new Document(Recatngle(216, n));
```

donde n es la suma de todos los altos (Heigth) tus items + Header + Footer + etc todos las lineas estaticas que imprimas.

**Lo mas complejo es el calculo del total de los altos de los items.**

yo lo hago así:

```
    int lineas = 0;
    foreach( var det in detalles)
    {
        lineas += (det.Descripcion.Length / 25) + (det.Descripcion.Length % 25 > 0? 1: 0 );
    }
```

La constante 25 corresponde al largo de la descripción el calculo del modulo es para considerar una línea adicional donde imprimo en mi caso el esto de descripción del producto.

Entonces el tamaño de papel final seria:

Rectangle( 216, nLineas+Header+Footer+Ohers); // (216 de ancho aproximadamente 8cmm) Y n de largo.

**El PDF de resultado seria algo así:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Execente, PepeLuna es justo lo que yo también hago!

Comment: Gracias, me sirvio!!!
Como dicen por en mi pais.... El que sabe sabe sino es jefe!